# Azure Functions – Time Trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am working with azure functions and it has timer trigger. I need to know if this expression means that the function will run every day of the week.
30 13,20 * * *

Comment: this is what I normally use for Cron https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the comma is a typo, as that's not a valid NCrontab expression, but yes,
`30 13 20 * * *` will run every day at 20:13:30.

There's a few out there, but check out e.g. https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/ - enter your NCrontab expression and it'll show you an set of occurrences for it.